# Join by location lines and points, reporting more attributes in the table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-join, lines-to-points

I have two layers, one of points and one of lines.
Visually, is something like thise:

[image]

As you can see, each line has two points, as it was a graph with vertices and edges.

The properties in the attributes table of the lines are only the IDs, the sames goes for the points.

I  tried a Join by location (intersection) and I got somethin like this:

[image]

So for each edge (segment) I have two rows, one relating it to a point, the second row connecting it to the other.

What I would like to obtain is having just a single row for each edge, with two related value (so two more columns, not only one), reporting the IDs of the two endpoint of that edge.

Comment: At least one of those lines is unconnected within the viewfield

Comment: Look at the aggregate tool.

Comment: @Vince How that is a helpful comment? that is just a screenshoot of a part of the example

Comment: It changes the problem if lines cross each other, and it visually distracts from the problem statement.

Comment: ok look only at the table then

Comment: @John thanks, it seems to be somethinge in here, even though it is kind of slow. is there no such way to do this DURING the join by location ?

Answer (score 0):

In the Field Calculator use:

```
array_to_string(overlay_intersects('Point',$id))
```

with layer Line and Point. The Point layer has a field with IDs.
The field type for the new field is array. Or you can use string.

[image]

**Solution 2**

You make two fields and for the first you sue this code:

```
(overlay_intersects('Point', $id))[0]
```

and for the second you use this code:

```
(overlay_intersects('Point',$id))[1]
```

**Snapping tolerance**

If you have problems with snapping the points you can try:

```
overlay_nearest('Point', $id, max_distance:=0.0001)[0]
```